# Typescript literal types and addition assignment operators

Tags: typescript, language-design, assignment-operator

For `typescript`'s [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/v2/docs/handbook/literal-types.html), behavior is different whether we use regular addition operators (e.g. `a = a + b`) or addition assignment operators (e.g. `a += b`):

```js
type SomeLiteralType = 1;

let a: SomeLiteralType = 1;

// Why is it possible to change the value of Literal type to unsupported value without any error?
a += 1;

// Now it's even not allowed to assign to itself - next error occurs: "Type 'number' is not assignable to type '1'"
a = a;
```

So eventually using addition assignment operators we can force variables to contain unexpected values.

The same happens for strings as well.

Is this an expected behavior and I've missed something in the documentation?

Answer (score -2):

1) `c += b;` and `a += a;` are, in relation to the type checking process equal.
The explanation whats going on could be found in `4)`.

2) `d = d + b;`
This expression will be interpreted by the compiler as following:
Assignment Expression:
 left side: `d`
 token (operator): `=`
 right side: `d + b`
In order to check the types on both sides, the compiler deducts the type for the right and left expression.
In case of the left side its simple.
For the right side it will be number.
The reason is that all mathematical operators (`+`, `-`, ...) are only possible with numbers (in jJavaScript) and so the result must be of type number as well.
With the deducted type `Odd` on the left side and number on the right you'll get your error.

3) `e = a + a;`
Same reason like the line above (`2)`)

4) `a += a;`
This expression boils down as following:
Assignment Expression: 
 left side: `a`
 token (operator): `+=`
 right side: `a`
Since we know from above, all mathematical operators could only be applied to numbers,
this should be self explanatory. The compiler checks if the left side is a number,
 which `a` is, and if the right side is a number. Either `a` or `1` are numbers so it works.

Why the last line works should now be clear and I'll leave it as a homework for you ;)

Comment: thank you for your answer. I've simplified the code example to emphasize the main problem.

Comment: Well may keep some of the examples, else a lot in my answer seems to be out of context ;)